# Pointwise product of uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

True or false: Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be uniformly continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
Then their pointwise product $f(x)g(x)$ is uniformly continuous.

I think it will be true; take $f(x)= g(x) = \sqrt x$.

Am I right or wrong?

Comment: You don't prove a statement true by finding an example for which the statement holds.

Comment: It would be true if you added "bounded" to your assumptions, but as stated JCSantos has the perfect counterexample in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false. Just take $f(x)=g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

The uniform continuity property refers to a spatially homogeneous behavior of continuity. Look at the graph of the following functions.

1. $f(x)=x$
2. $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$
3. $f(x)=x^2$
4. $$ f(x)= \begin{cases} 
   x\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x\ne 0 \\
   0 & x=0
   \end{cases}$$

Note that (2) has a "vertiginous behavior" around $0$, since that $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\to \infty$$ when $x\downarrow 0$. 
Also for (3) this behavior occurs when $|x|\to \infty$. 
(4) is continuous but is even "less uniform" than previous cases.